# Проблема с colspan и rowspan

Tags: html, html5

Не могу понять каким образом можно сдвинуть 6,8,11 ячейки, чтобы получилось как на картинке?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<html>
 <head>
 <title></title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="keywords" content="portfolio, html, design, practice">
  <meta name="description" content="Сайт ученика Васи с работами для поиска практики">
  <style>
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <table border="1"  cellspacing="0">
   <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" width="200px">1</td>
        <td colspan="2" width="150px" height="100px">2</td>
      </tr>
   <tr>
        <td height="120px" width="75px" >3</td>
        <td  height="120px" width="75px">4</td>
      </tr>
   <tr>
        <td  rowspan="2" height="120px">5</td>
        <td  height="60px">6</td>
        <td  height="50px">7</td>
      </tr>
   <tr>
      <td >8</td>
      <td rowspan="2" >9</td>


      </tr>
   <tr>
        <td height="40px" >10</td>
        <td>11</td>

      </tr>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1-й, 7-й и 9-й ячейкам надо добавить colspan="2":

```html
<table border="1"  cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="2" width="200px">1</td>
    <td colspan="2" width="150px" height="100px">2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="120px" width="75px" >3</td>
    <td  height="120px" width="75px">4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td  rowspan="2" height="120px">5</td>
    <td  height="60px">6</td>
    <td colspan="2" height="50px">7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td >8</td>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="2" >9</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="40px" >10</td>
    <td>11</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```